# Network Card speed stuck at 100 Mb/s

Tags: networking, windows-10, home-networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet

I have recently upgraded my Internet connection with my ISP (Movistar, Spain) and now I have a 600 Mbps one.

My Windows 10 computer (has a Gigabyte GA-Z87P-D3 motherboard) is capable of running a connection of 1Gbps, but it gets stuck at 100Mbps.

First of all, I've done some research and I configured the network card's speed to 1Gbps Full Duplex and upgraded the drivers to the latest version (a release from two days ago). This did not solve anything.

The second method I've tried was to change the Ethernet wire (CAT 5e, both of them) and to connect my laptop to the same both wires. The result was a 1Gbps connection on my laptop (with both wires) and still the 100Mbps connection on my PC.

I'm thinking on buying a new network card, but I prefer to explore other solutions before doing so.

I hope you can help me!

**EDIT**: I've tried downgrading the drivers and updating BIOS. Still the same.

I guess is not a router limitation, I can get the 600Mbps connection with my laptop with the same wire and plugged in the same "router spot" as my PC.

Comment: Don't rule out your modem/router. If it can't handle a speed greater than 100Mbps, you won't be getting better results by upgrading changing your network card or drivers.

Comment: @LPChip my router can handle it, I achieved the 600 Mbps with my laptop (and with the same wire which i have the PC connected).

Comment: @ArnauCastiella you ever manage to figure this one out my man? I'm in the exact same boat, after following the exact same steps with no luck.

Comment: @ballBreaker I ended up buying a new NIC from Amazon for barely 12 € and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: @ArnauCastiella Makes sense! I'm doing the same as well. Thnaks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to go, as you've already covered the 'obvious' [for which kudos, as many people don't do that before asking here ;)

1. Pick your way through the Advanced property sheet in `Device Manager/Network/[your NIC]/Advanced`... hoping you can see something misconfigured.
   My bet is you will do this anyway, because it's free & it makes sense.
2. Buy a can of contact cleaner spray & make sure the NIC's pins are clean.
   [Do this with the power off.]
   Cost - $£€ 5
3. Buy a new NIC, something generic but well-established, Atheros etc.
   Cost - $£€ 10.

tbh, you always should own a can of contact cleaner, but if you don't already, a new NIC is barely any more expensive.